# VSSADMIN Behavior when you press 'y' to "delete shadow copies"

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I have a bat file to do some cleanup on machines with minimal disk space. This bat file deletes windows restore points that eat up a lot of space via the command 'VSSADMIN List ShadowStorage'. It also optionally deletes log files, etc. I don't want to post the code because I don't want someone to copy it and delete all of their restore points on a machine that can't be restored to its current state!

The problem is that when I press 'y' in response to "Do you really want to delete..." the restore points are deleted properly and the program continues, but farther down it simply falls through a 'Set /P' command. It works fine if I press 'n'. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on here? I tried this on Windows 7 and 8.1.

Edit:
The reason this is happening is that VSSADMIN only requires a single key (no need to hit enter). I was pressing 'y' and ENTER (as I am sure some of my users will do). The ENTER key was then used by SET /P. Is there a way to clear any buffered keys before issuing the SET /P command?

Thanks!

Comment: Without the specific script, we can't tell you, the reason your script is failing.

Comment: Figured out why and will edit my post.. As I mentioned in the post... I did not post script because I do not want anyone to run it and delete all of their restore points unless they are doing it on a VM that can easily be reverted to its previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you're looking for exactly, but I wanted to provide it anyway *in case you find it useful or maybe sufficient as a workaround* to the problem you are describing.

Without seeing your logic and understanding the commands you run and so on, we have to make some assumptions unfortunately.

While your concern is understandable, you could add a "**WARNING:**" note indicating that it may be dangerous running it to help ensure anyone that might run it understands the ramifications you therein pointed out.

---

### COMMANDS

<sup>*You'd obviously need to change the drive letter from "C:" to whatever that in for your need*</sup>

*Piping the "Y" character to the **`VSSADMIN`** command so it always uses "**Y**" without the **`SET /P`**:*

```
ECHO Y | VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /FOR=C: /ALL
```

*Resizing the VSS allocated storage maxsize to ensure it never grows over this size per PC and per disk partition:*

```
VSSADMIN RESIZE SHADOWSTORAGE /FOR=C: /ON=C: /MAXSIZE=1GB
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**VSSADMIN**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754968(v=ws.11).aspx)